# matlab coder - change format in created C code

Tags: format, matlab-coder

I am using Matlab coder to port code to C, e.g. for the next function:

```
function sum_out = my_sum( x )
sum_out = 0;
for i=1:size(x,1)
    sum_out = sum_out + x(i);
end
end
```

The generated C code is:

```
double my_sum(const double x[10])
{
  double sum_out;
  int i;
  sum_out = 0.0;
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    sum_out += x[i];
  }
  return sum_out;
}
```

Is there a way to make the indentation 4 spaces?

Also, I would like to have the curly brackets in a separate line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Embedded Coder, the configuration settings `IndentSize` and `IndentStyle` allow you to tweak the behavior you've requested:

https://www.mathworks.com/help/coder/ref/coder.embeddedcodeconfig.html?s_tid=doc_ta

More generally, if you're looking for further customization of the generated code's formatting, you could consider running an external code formatting tool on it like `clang-format`.

The answer:

https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/391533-is-there-a-way-to-disable-line-wrapping-in-generated-c-code-from-matlab-coder

shows how you could automate that. I'll reproduce the steps here for completeness.

The Coder config setting `PostCodeGenCommand` allows you to run some MATLAB code after code generation finishes but before the C/C++ compiler runs. So you can use that to call `clang-format`.

- Make the file `doclangformat.m`:

  ```matlab
  function doclangformat(buildInfo)
  sourceFiles = join(buildInfo.getSourceFiles(true,true));
  sourceFiles = sourceFiles{1};
  cmd = ['clang-format -i -style=''{BasedOnStyle: LLVM, ColumnLimit: 20}'' ' sourceFiles]; 
  system(cmd);
  ```

  I've set `ColumnLimit` to 20 so the effect is obvious. The code will be drastically wrapped. You can view the other options in the [clang-format documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html).
- Set up the configuration object and call `codegen`:

  ```matlab
  cfg = coder.config('lib');
  cfg.PostCodeGenCommand = 'doclangformat(buildInfo)';
  codegen foo -config cfg <other codegen args>
  ```

Now you should see that your code is wrapped to about 20 columns.

The main downside of this approach is that the other Coder style settings like `IndentStyle`, `IndentSize`, etc. will need to be specified in your `clang-format` specification.